# Error gathering file system metadata with win32com.client

Tags: python, pywin32

I am working on a script that traverses a file system and gathers what file metadata it can (name, created date, size, etc).  It mainly does this using win32com.client

However, I keep getting this error when it hits on a special folder (specifically C:\Users<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History.  Note, however, that the error pops up even if the History folder is somewhere else, like a copy on a network drive.

I suspect it is the special nature of this folder (ie. Windows interprets the folder and displays the interpretation in Explorer, rather than the actual files and folders.

```
  File "C:\Users\olsont\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.8\50A7E9B0-70EF-11D1-B75A-00A0C90564FEx0x1x0.py", line 1750, in NameSpace
    ret = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(1610743810, LCID, 1, (9, 0), ((12, 1),),vDir)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147467259), None)
```

I am just getting use to win32com.client, and I am not finding a lot of tutorials or resources applicable to my use case, so I am completely in the dark.

Here are some of the relevant sections of code.

Creating the NameSpace object - this is what triggers the error for the History folder

```
sh = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Shell.Application',0)
ns = sh.NameSpace(sCurrPath)
```

The snippet from win32com.client that produces the error :

```
    # Result is of type Folder
    def NameSpace(self, vDir=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
        'Get special folder from ShellSpecialFolderConstants'
        ret = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(1610743810, LCID, 1, (9, 0), ((12, 1),),vDir
            )
        if ret is not None:
            ret = Dispatch(ret, 'NameSpace', '{BBCBDE60-C3FF-11CE-8350-444553540000}')
        return ret
```

The function that actually does the extracting of file metadata.  It doesn't get to this point for the History folder, but it does for all the other files.

```
def fFileDetails(ns, oItem, lColumns) :

    lKeepCols = ['Name', 'Extension', 'Item type', 'Path', 'Date created', 'Date modified', 'Attributes', 'Owner']

    dFileDetails = {}
    dFileDetails.setdefault('Path', oItem.Path)

    for colnum in range(len(lColumns)):
        sCurrCol = lColumns[colnum]
        colval=ns.GetDetailsOf(oItem, colnum)
        if sCurrCol in lKeepCols and colval:
            if sCurrCol in ['Path', 'Size'] :
                dFileDetails.setdefault(sCurrCol, eval(f'oItem.{sCurrCol}'))
            elif sCurrCol == 'Name' and not oItem.IsFolder and '.' in colval :
                sExt = fExtractExt(colval)
                dFileDetails.update({sCurrCol : colval, 'Extension' : sExt})
            else :
                dFileDetails.update({sCurrCol : colval})

    return dFileDetails
```

A bit of a brain dump, I know, but I am unsure what to do, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to know what is in the History folder? Why not just handle the exception and move on?

Comment: If possible, yes I'd like to parse the contents for a couple reasons.  If my theory is right, I may encounter other special folders, which may have contents I need to read.  On top of that, since this is an inventory script, I really would like to gather everything.